# Getting "EACCES" error in Node.js application

Tags: node.js, powershell, npm, npm-install

Today I updated the node version by uninstalling the old version. The recent version I installed was 4.5.0 LTS. After the installation, when I try to install a new npm, it doesn't work and gives me the following error

```
C:\Users\myuser
λ npm install -g yo
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "yo"
npm ERR! node v0.12.15
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! Error: connect EACCES
npm ERR!     at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
npm ERR!     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1012:19)
npm ERR!  { [Error: connect EACCES] code: 'EACCES', errno: 'EACCES', syscall: 'connect' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myuser\npm-debug.log
```

I have tried it using the command line with the Administrator privilege also in the Powershell. Tried to install several other plugins as well. Nothing works. Also switched off the firewall and tried, no luck. Installed the older version of NodeJS, issue is still persisting.

I'm using Windows 10. I checked whether am I behind a proxy, and I am not.

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions ?

Comment: @YanFoto Thanks for the comment, but I tried it, not working

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution for my question.

The issue was my virus guard Kespersky Endpoint Security 10 is blocking the node in my machine.

When I added it to the whitelist, it works perfectly.

Thanks