# Post request from Azure node.js web app to another server. problem with request: connect EACCES error

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a node.js based web app which I have hosted in an azure environment as a web service. I am trying to post some data to another server from my webapp to basically store the login details. I am getting an error problem with request: connect EACCES. However I am able to post data using postman to the same server. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You should update the error message of `Http Request` in the post in detail, so that it can help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From error message, I should add `Access Restriction` in your app services.

Related post:

[EACCESS Error in Node JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051127/eaccess-error-in-node-js/40105252)

From related post, I think you can `Add Access Restriction` in your app services.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, I am still not clear. Should I add my server details to this?

Comment: @Philomath The root cause of this problem is caused by the firewall, because the app service is a PaaS service and there is no physical server. So you can google to check the usage of `Add Access Restriction` and try it.